# Adding "bots" entry in Microsoft App Manifest: "A value without a type name was found"

Tags: botframework

I am using the online app manifest editor (portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/Manifest/appId/...) to add a custom bot to my app manifest. I am adding this part to the JSON:

```
"bots": [
{
  "botId": "[same-string-as-in-field-appId]",
  "scopes": [ "team", "personal", "groupchat" ]
}]
```

When I try to save the manifest though, I get:

"Failed to update [...] application. Error detail: A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value. [k+sF5]"

I assume this is due to a schema versioning issue but I don't know how to fix it. Or does it matter where the section is added? I just added it below all the other top-level JSON elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note:* Based on the data you added to the manifest, it looks like you're trying to create a Teams bot, so I've answered as such. If this is not the case, let me know and I'll edit my answer.

It looks like you're editing the wrong manifest. The manifests found in the Azure Portal (including the one you linked to) are deployment manifests for the Azure Resource. In this case, it's the deployment manifest for your App Registration.

What you need to do is build a manifest for your Teams bot. [Here's a link to the schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema). Here's an example based off one of my bots:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/teams/v1.7/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.7",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "<myAppId>",
  "packageName": "com.notification.bot",
  "localizationInfo": {
    "defaultLanguageTag": "en-us",
    "additionalLanguages": [
    ]
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "My Name",
    "websiteUrl": "https://dev.botframework.com/",
    "privacyUrl": "https://aka.ms/bf-privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://aka.ms/bf-terms",
    "mpnId": "<random ID>"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Notification Bot",
    "full": "GitHub Issue Notification Bot"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "GitHub Issue Notification Bot",
    "full": "GitHub Issue Notification Bot"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "outline.png",
    "color": "color.png"
  },
  "accentColor": "#fc4103",
  "configurableTabs": [
  ],
  "staticTabs": [
  ],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "<myAppId>",
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "personal",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "needsChannelSelector": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "commandLists": [
      ]
    }
  ],
  "connectors": [
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "devicePermissions": [
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "token.botframework.com"
  ],
  "showLoadingIndicator": false,
  "activities": {
  }
}
```

After that, you need to [create your upload package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/apps-package). As you can see, it consists of:

1. The manifest.json we created above
2. A colored, 192x192 icon
3. A white and transparent 32x32 icon

[Here's a link to one of our samples that has all three of these items](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/57.teams-conversation-bot/TeamsAppManifest).

You then zip all of these up and [upload your bot/app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload)

Comment: Yes, it's for a Teams bot. I'll let you know if I can solve this based on your hints. Thanks!

Comment: It all worked fine, thanks so much. I added the bot to my teams tenant. Now I will have to figure out how to actually connect to the API.